# How to use .map (or other) to change the values of several columns in a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df with similar categorical ordinal values that I'd like to change into a numerical scale. 
A mock df to try to explain:

```
data = {'Fruit':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'Weight':[23, 45, 31, 28, 62, 12, 44, 42, 23, 32], 
        'Taste':['good', 'so so', 'very good', 'awful', 'awful', 'very good', 'good', 'good', 'awful', 'good'],
       'Look':['good', 'good', 'so so', 'awful', 'so so', 'very good', 'very good', 'good', 'awful', 'good']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to change the values in 'Taste' and 'Look' from very good etc to 4-1. If it were one column I'd just write: `df['Taste'] = df['Taste'].map({'very good': 4, 'good': 3, 'so so': 2, 'awful': 1})`
but that doesn't work with `df[['Taste', 'Look']] = df[['Taste', 'Look']].map({'very good': 4, 'good': 3, 'so so': 2, 'awful': 1})`
I've also tried with: `df.update(df[['Taste', 'Look']].map({'very good': 4, 'good': 3, 'so so': 2, 'awful': 1}))` which doesn't work.

Any tips and tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `get`:

```
d = {'very good': 4, 'good': 3, 'so so': 2, 'awful': 1}
df[['Taste', 'Look']] = df[['Taste', 'Look']].applymap(d.get)
```

Solution with `map` is possible, but need `stack` with `unstack`:

```
df[['Taste', 'Look']] = df[['Taste', 'Look']].stack().map(d).unstack()

print (df)
   Fruit  Weight  Taste  Look
0      1      23      3     3
1      2      45      2     3
2      3      31      4     2
3      4      28      1     1
4      5      62      1     2
5      6      12      4     4
6      7      44      3     4
7      8      42      3     3
8      9      23      1     1
9     10      32      3     3
```

Comment: Thank you - helpful as always.